# How to join to single row in one to many relationship in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to join one to many table with single row on many table by limit 1 and order by create date

```
tbl_cart :

id   fullname
 1   myname1
 2   myname2
 3   myname3

tbl_cart_status:

id   cart_id   status  created_at
1     1         33      2018-09-20
2     1         34      2018-09-23
3     2         34      2018-09-21
4     1         100     2018-09-25
5     2         35      2018-09-29
```

How can i get output with sql like this:
I want to get lastest status of my cart by ordered with created_at column

```
myname   cart_id   status    created_at
myname1     1         100     2018-09-25
myname2     2         35      2018-09-29
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think filtering for this type of query:

```
select c.name, cs.*
from tbl_cart c join
     tbl_cart_status cs
     on c.id = cs.cart_id
where cs.created_at = (select max(cs2.created_at)
                       from tbl_cart_status cs2
                       where cs2.cart_id = cs.cart_id
                      );
```

Comment: mysql error on tbl_cart_status cs2 said Unknown table tbl_cart_status

Comment: but i can run sub query alone

Comment: @Fadakar . . . That table is defined i n your question.

Comment: table exist in my DB and run alone select max(cs2.created_at)
                       from tbl_cart_status cs2 and work fine but error in subquery

Comment: I don't now why